# Advice on hunting for PHP errors on a live page

Tags: php, error-handling, live

**Background**
On live environments you have to fix things from time to time. After you publish your code, some errors or glitches may slip through and go live on your page.
Users often do not report back on the errors so the page is broken until you discover it on your own.

**Question**
Is there a recommended way in PHP to detect something that is broken when there is a PHP error  besides the PHP log?

For example, would you recommend to place a code that emails you if an error occurs on the page?

Thank you

Comment: 1. php should log that 2. there should be a software that monitors logs. So split these two. And, not, emailing right from php generally is not a good idea

Comment: Do you know any practical solution that can be applied to the server or somehow that would scan the log and report on any error or similar? Would be cool :)

Comment: The most robust bet, though it's not so much use implementing retroactively, is to develop against a testing framework of some kind. You can then run your tests when you're ready to deploy/publish, and only continue if they all pass. Of course, that's not a miracle cure for bugs either.

Comment: @fuzzydunlop sometimes, especially when you have many many users, there might not be the time to test the code you write for example if you got much to do and are the only dev of the project. And neither less, even if you do some testing on your own, there are times where it simply slips through no matter what you do :(

Comment: @Herr Kaleun: the problem of log monitoring has nothing to do with programming, it is OS-specific system administration question

Comment: @zerkms well, I was thinking about if the PHP error occurs, you can have some code on that page like sendmail() & etc. Actually that part has something to do with programming.

Comment: @Herr Kaleun: and that's not a good idea - not every error may be handled. Do you need a partial or robust solution? Anyway, I adviced a common way (that works in every case and is used widely) of doing that, you can choose whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start maximizing the use of `Exception` http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php and creation of custom `set_error_handler` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php with this features you can begin to categories your error and diffident format for notification

Example

`GreenException` Save to MongoDB log

`BlueException` Send to Review

`WhiteException` Send me a Mail

`UnknownException` Send me a SMS

You should also try to make during development the following settings are turn on and never suppress any error

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Develop your application in such a way where everything is validated and verified

Example (File Upload) or else throw Exception

Can I upload

File Was Updated

Is it a valid File

Does the destination folder exist

Is it writable

Copy File

Was File successfully copied

etc .....

This way you would minimize production errors

Last always  ... do `unit testing` .....

Comment: if you use `mail` use capture the error and use `SMTP` if there is error , you capture  the error it and save it to message queue ... if there is an error ... finally after all attempt you save to file

Comment: why to complicate so much if you can only log everything and process the logs? The universal way, instead of dozen specifics. Btw, the `mail sending code` is not limited to only one `mail` function - you could make a mistake somewhere **above**. What then? Why to hardcode the way of notification (email, sms, etc) in the place of handling instead of delaying it to the *logs process* stage (when you're free to do whatever and whenever you want)?

Comment: The why why they invented `escalation` ...  Some error are more important than the other .. universal  storage would not work .. secondly .. some errors might have some backup operation ... that is my i said if `POP3` does nto work use `SMTP` ...